# Using different repositories for different libs in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have two repositories, for example myRepo.com and myRepo2.com . All my artifacts are in both repos, but for some reasons, i want to some of them to be downloaded from first repo, and another from second (for example myLib should be downloaded from myRepo and myLib2 from myRepo2). Is it possible?
I'm using gradle 2.2.
thanks in advance!

Comment: out of curiousity. Can you share a bit more about your usecase?

Comment: It's complicated - long story short - i had to migrate to another repo and revert project version to 1.0 (which already exist in old repo), but i still need some others project from old repo. There are easy solutions to my problem, like change projects versions, but i was curious if there is more elegant way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Gradle. When you have two repositories declared in your Gradle build script, gradle will look the repositories in the declared order and pick your libraries from the first repo they are available from.